# How to auto logout user after certain period of time of loggedin.

Tags: python, django, session, logout

I am working on a website to host a competition on local server.Actually the time limit of competition is 60 min.**I want to auto logout every user after 60 min of logging In.**

I am beginner to django and this is my first project in django.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 6):

Add global settings (`SESSION_COOKIE_AGE`) in your `settings.py` file in seconds to timeout.

Ex.:

**settings.py**

```
...
SESSION_COOKIE_AGE = 60 * 60 # 60 minutes
...
```

Answer (score 3):

Please refer to `set_expiry(value)` method in [How to use sessions](https://docs.djangoproject.com/zh-hans/2.0/topics/http/sessions/)

If `value` above is an integer, the session will expire after that seconds of inactivity.

For example, calling

```
request.session.set_expiry(300)
```

would make the session expire in 5 minutes.